# how to manage the conflict between the Ajax handler and the form's action on octobercms

Tags: ajax, laravel, octobercms

I would like to put the data of a form into a session

The action of the form depends on the choice made  in  the buttons `.bien` especially in the onclick() function .

for that I made this code:

---

```
title = "formulaire_commun_1"
url = "/formulaire_commun_1"
layout = "sidebar_layout"
is_hidden = 0
==


<?php
function onStart()
{
    $this['transaction'] = Session::get('transaction');
     $this['bien'] = Session::get('type_bien');
}

function onTest()
{


    Session::put('transaction', input('TYPE_transaction'));
    Session::put('type_bien', input('radio_type_bien'));
}

function onRedirectMe()
{
    return Redirect::to('http://google.com');
}

?>
==





 <ul class="progressbar">
 <li class="active">transaction</li>
 <li>details</li>
 <li>confirmation</li>
 </ul>

 <br><br><br><br>




 <form   method="POST"  data-request="onTest" data-request-success="onRedirectMe"  name="formu" accept-charset="UTF8"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="_handler" value="onUpdate">
                {{form_token()}}
                {{form_sessionkey()}}
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="TYPE_transaction" class="col-sm-3">type de transaction:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
     <select class="form-control" id="TYPE_transaction" name="TYPE_transaction">
    <option>vendre</option>
    <option>louer</option>

  </select>
    </div>
    <br><br><br>


 <p>choisissez un type de bien:</p>
 <br><br>

<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2">
 <button class="btn btn-default bien" onclick="type_bien(0)" >
  <img src="{{ 'assets/img/icones/icone_maison.png'|theme }}">
 </button>
</div>

 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2">

 <button class="btn btn-default bien"   onclick="type_bien(1)"><img src="{{ 'assets/img/icones/icone_villa.jpg'|theme }}"></button>

 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2">
 <button class="btn btn-default bien"   onclick="type_bien(2)"><img src="{{ 'assets/img/icones/icone_riad.jpg'|theme }}"></button>

 </div>


<br><br><br><br><br>

<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2">
 <button class="btn btn-default bien"   onclick="type_bien(3)"><img src="{{ 'assets/img/icones/icone_appartement.png'|theme }}"></button>

  </div>
 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2">

 <button class="btn btn-default bien"   onclick="type_bien(4)"><img src="{{ 'assets/img/icones/icone_ferme.png'|theme }}"></button>

 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-2">
 <button class="btn btn-defaul bien"   onclick="type_bien(5)"><img src="{{ 'assets/img/icones/icone_magasin.jpg'|theme }}"></button>


 </div>

 <br><br><br><br>


<div style="display: none;">
 <div class="radio" >
<label><input type="radio" name="radio_type_bien" id=0  value="maison" ></label>

 </div>
  <div class="radio"  >
 <label><input type="radio" name="radio_type_bien" id=1  value="villa"></label>

 </div>
  <div class="radio"  >
<label><input type="radio" name="radio_type_bien" id=2 value="riad" ></label>

 </div>
  <div class="radio"   >
<label><input type="radio" name="radio_type_bien" id=3  value="appartement" ></label>

 </div>
  <div class="radio"  >
<label><input type="radio" name="radio_type_bien" id=4  value="formulaire_appartement" ></label>

 </div>
  <div class="radio"   >
<label><input type="radio" name="radio_type_bien" id=5 value="magasin" ></label>

 </div>


 </div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br



<div class=" col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>


</div></div>


</form> 





<script type = "text/javascript">

           $(function() {

               var $buttonBien = $('.bien');

                $buttonBien.on('click',function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                });


           });


function type_bien(x){

    switch( x) {
    case 0:


        document.getElementById(0).checked="true";
        document.forms["formu"].action="formulaire_villa";


        break;
    case 1:

        document.getElementById(1).checked="true";
        document.forms["formu"].action="formulaire_villa";


        break;
    case 2:

        document.getElementById(2).checked="true";
        document.forms["formu"].action="formulaie_riad";

        break;

    case 3:


        document.getElementById(3).checked="true";
        document.forms["formu"].action="formulaire_appartement";


        break;
    case 4:

        document.getElementById(4).checked="true";

        break;
    case 5:

        document.getElementById(5).checked="true";

        break;
    default:
         alert('local_commerce est selected');
}

}


</script>
_____________
```

---

but unfortunately there is a conflict between ajax and the  form
if i put `data-request = "onTest" action = ""` for example

I have no redirection

so I need a way to redirect the form to another page after the submit:

please help me

thank you in advance

Comment: may be check my answer its related to this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343015/3076866

Comment: thank you ,gentlman