# how to change the direction of a form dynamicly with ajax or javascript in octobercms

Tags: javascript, ajax, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have a form, and I would like it when I submit it, that it redirects me
in another page,

knowing that the redirection  path must be dynamic,

it means that I use a javascript function that takes the user's choice and return a string

the ajax handler **data-request-redirect** only accept a string and execute not javascript code:

---

```
title = "test"
url = "/test"
layout = "default"
is_hidden = 0
==
<?php
function onStart()
{
    $this['example'] = Session::get('example-key');
}

function onTest()
{
    Session::put('example-key', input('my-input'));
}

?>
==

<form   method="POST"  data-request="onTest" data-request-redirect="......" name="formu" accept-charset="UTF8"  enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <input type="text" name="my-input">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

{% if example %}
    <strong>Example: {{ example }}</strong>
{% endif %}


<script type = "text/javascript">

           $(function() {

               var $buttonBien = $('.bien');

                $buttonBien.on('click',function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                });


           });


function type_bien(x){

    switch( x) {
    case 0:
       return "formulaire_villa";

        break;
    case 1:

                    return "formulaire_villa";
        break;
    case 2:
                   return "formulaie_riad";
        break;

    case 3:


        document.getElementById(3).checked="true";
       /* document.forms["formu"].action="formulaire_appartement";*/

            return "formulaire_appartement";
        break;

    default:
         alert('local_commerce est selected');
}

}


</script>
```

---

so what to do in the ***data-request-redirect***

I am really blocked

please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be simple thing is to use `Redirect` facade.

> when you use `October Ajax framework` you can send redirect from server.

so from your function / code section.

```
use Redirect;

function onTest()
{
    $defaultUrl = '/home';

    // you get data from post
    // from hidden or select etc ...
    $someChoise = post('some-choise');

    if($someChoise == 'my-profile') {
        $defaultUrl = '/user/profile';
    }

    Session::put('example-key', input('my-input'));
    return Redirect::to($defaultUrl);
}
```

> `more info on Redirect facade` https://octobercms.com/docs/services/response-view#redirects

Now it will automatically redirect webpage to `/home` when nothing specified

if you specify `some-choise` as `my-profile` it will redirect page to `/user/profile`

> so in this way you can even pass `url in post data` and use it, you don't need to do anything fancy [ so you can omit `data-request-redirect`]

data-request-redirect is string so its static data may be you can update it but above way is better for dynamic redirect url I guess. [ `redirect specified as string` => https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api#javascript-api ]

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: thank you hardik, you always save my life,thank you very much